# Cannot load files in UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: objective-c, uidocumentinteraction

I am building an app that allows the opening of a PDF, and handles this like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)source annotation:(id)annotation
{   
    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL])
    {
        if ([[url pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"pdf"])
        {
            FilePreviewViewController *filePreviewController = [[FilePreviewViewController alloc] init];
            [filePreviewController setURL:url];

            [self.navController pushViewController:filePreviewController animated:NO];

            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

And then in `FilePreviewController.m`:

```
-(void) setURL:(NSURL *) URL
{
    self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];

    [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

    [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:NO];
}
```

However, when I open a file and the view transitions, I get these messages:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <QLRemotePreviewContentController: 0x1581fe00>.

Couldn't issue file extension for path: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6399D00B-47A1-4F33-B34C-3F0B07B648AE/Documents/Inbox/pdf-8.pdf
```

And the file itself does not load.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because this works fine on the simulator (i.e. the PDF loads and displays perfectly).

Answer (score 0):

use this code to view/read pdf format file.

```
    .h
    <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>

     UIDocumentInteractionController *controller;

.m

NSString *File_name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",URL];
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docDir,[File_name lastPathComponent]];

            NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    if (pdfData) {

                        [pdfData writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];


                        controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController  interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pngFilePath]];
                        controller.delegate = self;
                        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, appDelegate.wVal, appDelegate.hVal);
                        [controller presentOptionsMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];

                    }
                });
            });
```